# dynamically increate the listbox column width with form resizes

Tags: vb.net

I want the ability to auto stretch the listview control column when the form gets resized in vb.net 2008

These are the properties I am mentioning for the ListView now :

```
 ListView1.View = View.Details
        'ListView1.GridLines = True
        ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
        ListView1.HideSelection = False
        ListView1.MultiSelect = True


        ListView1.Columns.Add("Listing", ListView1.Width, HorizontalAlignment.Center)


        ListView1.Items.Add("tet")
```

I am using form_resize event but it is not giving what I want

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        ListView1.Width = Me.Width
    End Sub
```

I am increasing the width of control and not columns as I wanted. I am unable to find anything else than width.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you do not have to set the Form1_Resize, you can achive this using the *Anchor* property of the ListView.

Set this to **Top,Bottom,Left,Right**

Secondly, try using the resize event of the *ListView*

Something like

```
Private Sub ListView1_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Resize
    If ListView1.Columns.Count > 0 Then
        ListView1.Columns(0).Width = ListView1.Width
    End If
End Sub
```